# .net Core 3.0 Preview 2 - [406: Not Acceptable]

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I build an Web API using Microsoft 2.2, based on Microsoft Documentation.
Everything was working as expected.

After updating to .net Core 3.0 Preview 2, all endpoints are returning [406: Not Acceptable].

There is something missing, but so far i wasn't able to understand what is missing. The following code its the same as on .net core 2.2.

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        //.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) => { });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Dependency Injection - Services
        services.AddSingleton<IXXXService, XXXService>();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
            c.EnableAnnotations();
        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API"); });
    }
}
```

**XXXController.cs**

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/xxx")]
public class XXXController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IXXXService _service;

    public XXXController(IXXXService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Produces("application/json", Type = typeof(PagedDto<XXX>))]
    [SwaggerOperation(
        Summary = "Gets all the XXX",
        Description = "Requires admin privileges",
        OperationId = "GetAllXXX",
        Tags = new[] {"XXX"}
    )]
    public IActionResult GetAllXXX([FromQuery] PagingDto pagging)
    {
        return Ok(_service.GetAllXXX(pagging));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I posted this question in Microsoft github, and this was their response:

```
You have to install the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
In your startup.cs file, add the JsonFormatter like this :
```

`services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);`

With this change, everything is working as expected.

Comment: That's probably the biggest change in aspnet core 3 - JSON.NET now is no longer bundled.